# jQuery-File-Upload: исключить добавление дублирующих файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в jQuery-File-Upload можно сделать проверку (client side) на уже добавленный в fileupload файл?

Например, я добавляю картинку, которая находится директории "c:\img\1\test.jpg". Затем, я как бы случайно решил добавить ту же самую картинку с этой же директории. Мне нужно, чтобы если эта картинка уже была добавлена, то в консоль выдавалось сообщение.

Но если, я скопирую эту картинку в другую директорию, например, в  "c:\img\22\test.jpg", то при ее добавлении не нужно выдавать, что она дублируется с  c:\img\1\test.jpg.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать. Спасибо!

Comment: При добавлении файла записывайте все директории в массив, а потом проверяйте

Comment: @Yuri А где находятся эти директории? В объекте data.files содержатся только lastModified = 1447862622000, lastModifiedDate = Wed Nov 18 2015 19:03:42 GMT+0300 (MSK) , name = 5422464000.jpg, size = 1396773, type = image/jpeg?

Comment: Там когда вы выбираете файл. Можно из него получить полную директорию. Не из самого файла нужно тащить, а из `input file`. Если хотите, могу в ответе указать как

Comment: @Yuri, Укажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Простите, ошибочка вышла. Уже нельзя узнать полную. Теперь это противоречит правилам конденфиальности